# What is the relationship betwen Class and Widget in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-widget, flutter-layout

Since there are tons of Widgets and Class and properties in flutter.
So i am confuse in between Widgets property and certain class property. How we should map the Widget and Propery during implementation. Because there are Some case when we map as Widget -> Property -> and then Widget.And another situation as Scaffold has a appBar Property which
has a AppBar() constuctor.

**Does we need to remember all different kind of situations in each widgets in flutter or there is any techniques to understand the pattern ?**

So when we can implement constructor or property to doing task. It is very confusing.

I scratch my head to the wall for understanding the proper various kind of mapping between Widgets , Property , Constructor to implements.

**"I will appreciate your help with this situation."**

Answer (score 0):

In **Flutter** all the Widgets are created using class.
Flutter have lot of widgets, you need to find which widget is suitable for your situation.

You can find lot of widgets by Category [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets)

Every widget have own properties, with the help of properties you can customize the design, shape or color anything with the widget.

**Example:** Appbar have properties like title for appbar name, leading property for appbar header icon, backgroundColor property for change the color of the appbar.

You don't need to remember all the properties of the all the widgets. because flutter is open source so if you are using **Android Studio** or **VS Code**. 
You can view all the properties of widgets by pressing ctrl and mouse hover on particular widget or pressing ctrl+ space in when cursor inside widget.

You can also create your own widgets and use it in your Application.

Answer (score 0):

you write class with dart language which is Object oriented language.

Flutter takes those classes and makes Widgets, which are hold by element tree. The element tree also holds the state objects associated with stateful widgets.

if we look inside runApp func call (starting point of flutter app)

```dart
void runApp(Widget app) {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
    ..scheduleAttachRootWidget(app)
    ..scheduleWarmUpFrame();
}
```

it sets your root Widget and from there on uses sublinear widget making through the nested widgets to get to the bottom.

[sublinear widget making](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/inside-flutter)

hope it hepls.